# How do I select related data from different tables and use it to show trend in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these three tables which represent performance in various subjects for three cat series:

```
CAT1
adm_no eng mat bio che phy
1111    90  87  89  74  92
2222    65  87  54  65  87
3333    96  95  98  58  56
4444    58  28  88  74  85


CAT2
adm_no eng mat bio che phy
1111    40  82  81  79  90
2222    67  88  78  67  84
3333    97  99  95  24  78
4444    82  22  83  76  90


CAT3
adm_no eng mat bio che phy
1111    80  45  86  74  96
2222    95  87  56  65  83
3333    46  97  84  58  87
4444    78  23  80  74  83
```

I'd like to get the performance trend in subjects for every student. For instance, if I'd wish to get the performance trend for eng, then the result would be be something like this:

```
adm_no CAT1 CAT2 CAT3
1111   90   40   80
2222   65   67   95
3333   96   97   46
4444   58   82   78
```

How would I be able to achieve this using mysql and php? Secondly and most important, how would it be achievable in case the number of tables is not static? (it could be two or even four).

Comment: will the name of tables always follow this convention? like CAT1, CAT2, CAT3, CAT4 ?

Comment: Yes, after cat3, the next should be cat4.

Comment: Ok, check my answer. Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It looked a little cryptic at first, but I got the logic. It works just the way I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: the answer that you chosen as correct answer was not the one I gave

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I've just  chosen it as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @NdalilaTony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you will have atleast cat1. The query is basically what scaisEdge provided on his answer. However, this will give you an idea how to dynamically generate it with PHP. The below function will build the query that you can use to get your desired result.

```
function buildQuery($subject) {
    $select .= "select `cat1`.adm_no, `cat1`.`$subject` as CAT1";
    $from = ' from cat1';
    $i = 2;
    while (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cat$i'"))) {
        $table = "cat$i";
        $label = "CAT$i";
        $previousTable = 'cat'.($i-1);
        $select .= ", `$table`.`$subject` as $label";
        $from .= " inner join $table on `$table`.adm_no = `$previousTable`.adm_no ";
        $i++;
    }
    return $select.$from;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you shuold use inner join between tre three tables

```
select a.adm_no, a.eng as CAT1, b.eng as CAT2, c.eng as CAT3
from table1 as a 
inner join table2 as b on a.adm_no = b.adm_no
inner join table3 as c on a.adm:no = c.adm_no
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. So, what would it be like in case I'm not sure of the number of tables so that the results generated are dynamic. I intend to loop through the tables available and thereafter generate an appropriate query.

Comment: Server side you can build a dinamic sql .. for the table you need  and add the related inner join